# PHP simple HTML DOM Parser: getting "Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm trying to parse a cinema webpage and get the movie schedule for the upcoming days.
The following code shows what I've done till now:

```
foreach ($html -> find('div[id*=tabs]') as $days) {
    foreach($days -> find('div[!class]') as $good_days) {
        echo $good_days
        foreach($good_days -> find('a') as $title) {
            if (empty($movie_names)) {          
                $movie_names[] = $title;
            }
            if (!in_array($title, $movie_names)) {
                $movie_names[] = $title;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I keep the code at echo $good_days, everything goes smoothly and I get a table-like of the scheduled movies, as shown in the picture:
[echo $good_days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyym9.png)
If I try to get only the names of the movies, I get the first day titles, and as it starts parsing the second I get

> Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

on the

```
if (in_array($title, $movie_names)) {
```

line. I don't get what is wrong with the code and I can't understand the error at all.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try to clear `if` after `foreach($good_days -> find('a') as $title) {` and try `echo $title;`?

Comment: And what is the version of php?

Comment: Thanks for that. I find the solution. I had to set `$title->plaintext`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I just had to set `$title->plaintext`